# Want to execute two commands in windows batch file one by one

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to send the spool files to printer from spool folder one by one and after processing each file it will be moved to another folder or delete it.
But When I'm trying to run below batch file it directly moves spool files without sending to printer which is due to batch processing.

```
 for %%f in (C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\*.SPL) do (
            echo %%~nf
            start "" E:\spool\xyz\tp.exe "C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\%%~nf.SPL" "HP Printer"
            move "C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\%%~nf.SPL" d:\%%~nf.txt
        )
```

SO need any alternative option without using windows PowerShell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because of the batch processing. By default batch waits on the termination of a command before moving on. So leaving out the `start` should do.
The problem is actually the [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command. By default [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) will execute the program as a new process and won't wait for it to finish. Use [`start /WAIT`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) instead, the `/WAIT` option will ask it to wait. But as I said earlier, you don't even need `start`.
Supposing your program exits when it has completed its task, you should do:

```
for %%f in ("C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\*.SPL") do ( 
    echo %%~nf
    E:\spool\xyz\tp.exe "%%~ff" "HP Printer"
    move "%%~ff" d:\%%~nf.txt 
)
```

In general that should do. But if the program `E:\spool\xyz\tp.exe` itself starts some kind of background process and exits without waiting for it to terminate, even `start /WAIT` won't help. As I don't know the program you're using (`E:\spool\xyz\tp.exe`) I won't be able to help you in that case.

**EDIT**: Just a little improvement I made in the code: you don't need to specify the whole path to get the file corresponding to the loop variable, `%%~ff` will do it for you (see [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ben/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file/) for others).

Comment: Why use `START` at all? Just the command `E:\spool\xyz\tp.exe etc...` will cause the batch file to wait.

Comment: @J.Baoby I tried your solution but spool files were not sent to printer it directly moved to another location. And abot tp.exe program it just sends spool file to printer for printing nothing to deal with it.I tried with powershell it working fine with PoweShell.But some old windows PC don't have powershell So need it to do in batch file.

Comment: @dev.Sumit it worked for me with another executable. Are you sure `tp.exe` always exits once the spool file are actually sent? Could it be it starts another process that will connect to the printer and send the files instead of sending it itself?

Comment: @dev.Sumit It would also help if you could add the PowerShell command that worked in your post

Comment: @J.Baoby Not yet sir, I'm completing my remaining coding and at last I will go for solution with full energy.Meanwhile if you find any solution please shere here.

Comment: @dev.Sumit The answer I posted is the only solution I can give you without knowing your program. As explained in the answer, this is the batch way to execute a command after **the previous command exits**. But for some programs, exit is not the same as "finish the task" (probably the case for your program). For those programs, the ways to know if they finished must be found in their documentation/implementation (can be polling some flag, registry, existence of a file,...). That's why I asked if you could add the equivalent powershell code in your original post. It may help.

Comment: @dev.Sumit When the time comes, you can edit your post and leave a comment. I'll then try to help